# How do you say 'to die from...' in Japanese?

Tags: translation, particles, expressions

For instance, I'm trying to say 'I would die from boredom' and the best I can come up with is

> 死ぬのから退屈だ

However, I strongly suspect this isn't correct. It would also be useful to have the phrase "I suffer from..." laid out as well.

Comment: Pardon the silly question: are you trying to talk about **literally** dying, or are you using it as a **figure of speech** (to express "I would be extremely bored")?

Comment: May I suggest using a dictionary? http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=die+of+boredom

Comment: I'm assuming it was a figure of speech...人間はどんなに退屈でも死にはしませんから(笑) Luckily you can use the same figure of speech in Japanese.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Japanese. We can't be confident in a translation without knowledge like who you're talking to, your relative status, written or spoken, what setting, etc. etc.

退屈で死ぬ would mean "to die from boredom". で is often used to mark the means or cause of something (cf. 病気で死ぬ=die from an illness, 水不足で死ぬ=die from dehydration, etc). Note that the particle marks what is before it. So you could say like 退屈で死ぬかもしれない for 'I would die from boredom'. To a friend in everyday conversation though, I would probably say something more like 退屈すぎて死ぬわ.

Comment: 死ぬほど退屈　is also a common way to say "bored to death"